# Dynamic UITableView is not calling the delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I need to add a table view in a specific are of my screen which is inside another UIView. When the user press a button the table view is created and displayed perfectly fine. However I need to know the user selection so I create it in the following way:

```
self.dynamicTableView = UITableView(frame: self.viewForTableView.bounds)
self.dynamicTableView?.dataSource = self
self.dynamicTableView?.delegate = self
self.messageZone.addSubview(self.dynamicTableView!)
self.dynamicTableView?.reloadData()
```

The data sources methods are being called but the delegate is not, so the following println is not working

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Hello")
}
```

As additional information I'm using a custom table view cell

UPDATE: I just discover that if I implement `shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath` sometimes if I do a long press it works, like if I keep the cell pressed for about four seconds, but not always, just some times. Can it be any view that is behind the table view what is causing this weird behaviour?

Comment: Are any of the other delegate methods being called? Like `heightForRowAtIndexPath` or `estimatedHeightFor...`. Do the cells have a button or text field or anything that could be stealing touches from the table view?

Comment: Couriously `tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` and `tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` are being called, but not `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` and `tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath?`

Comment: Are they being called? Not being called?

Comment: the first two are being called, but not the others (didSelectRowAtIndexPath and willSelectRowAtIndexPath)

Comment: Then your custom table view cells are receiving the touches instead of your table view. Post the storyboard/xib/code of your table view cells.

Comment: I tried with traditional UITableViewCell and they doesn't receive the touch events either...

Comment: Verify in the interface builder that `Selection` is not set to `No Selection`, `Show Selection on Touch` is checked and `User Interaction Enabled` is checked on the table view. Also verify that `User Interaction Enabled` is checked on the cell itself.